# Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'xxxx', when I use generics type inside generic method

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I am getting error while trying to use generic type inside the method.

My method has too many logics, I just added a code snippet

Generics Method:

```
public void MyGenericMethod<T, T1>(List<T1> arg1) where T : IInterface, new()
    {
        var useMethod = typeof(T);
        Moq.Setup(x => x.useMethod(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
          .Throws(new Exception("MoqException"));
        var returnDataList = MyService.arg1(new DateTime(), "12345");
    }
```

Actual Method:

```
public void SampleMethod()
    {
        Moq.Setup(x => x.GetCustomerMethod(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
         .Throws(new Exception("MoqException"));
        var returnDataList = MyService.GetServiceMethod(new DateTime(), "12345");
    }
```

Error: Throws in this line `Moq.Setup(x => x.useMethod (It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new Exception("MoqException"));` for useMethod.

I am learning generics in c#. Please help me to resolve.

Comment: At what line in the posted code are you getting the error?

Comment: I am sorry to sat, but your code does not make much sense. You have a method argument `arg1` which your code does not use - but you call a method of the *MyService* type which has the name "arg1" - that looks like you confused something. Also you have a Type variable `method` (refering to the Type object for the type T) which you also don't use - but you access a method called "method" like `x.method(...)` -- your code looks very confusing and like you just tried writing some random stuff and hoped the compiler will chew it... - Perhaps explain what you tried to achieve with this code snippet.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: modified the code in the question and getting an exception in "useMethod" from the following line  Moq.Setup(x => x.useMethod (It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new Exception("MoqException"));

Comment: What is the type of your `Moq` field/property? It probably is `Mock<Something>`, right?  Now, whatever "Something" is in your particular case, any x in your lambda expression will be of this `Something` type. Does this type implement a "useMethod" method? (hint: The compiler tells you it does not)

Comment: @elgonzo: You are right. x.method was a mistake while modifying the code to simpler. I changed the above code accordingly. I've not implemented to call the generic method in SampleMethod(). That's why you don't see the arg1 stuff over there. The above example is to show "what lines of code I am trying to implement in generics". Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @elgonzo: That's a property in an interface Eg. " private Mock<ICustomer> Moq { get; set; }". This ICustomer(I mentioned this interface in my generics method as IInterface) interface has "useMethod"

Comment: Well, but the compiler disagrees. Either your ICustomer interface does not declare a "useMethod" method, or the Moq field/property is not of type *Mock<ICustomer>*, or you have several different ICustomer interfaces in your project (in different namespaces) and you got confused about which one is which...

Comment: yeah! I missed to include it in ICustomer Interface. In my generics "MyGenericMethod<T, T1>" now, T doesn't use anywhere in the generics method.

Comment: What version of Moq are you using?  Current version does not seem to have a `Moq.Setup` method.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, it looks like Moq4: https://github.com/Moq/moq4

Comment: @PeterRitchie or he could have a `Mock<T>` field called `Moq`, that does have a `Setup` method.

Comment: yea. I am using moq v4.

Comment: I still don't see a Moq.Setup in 4.0.  @Freesiah What is `Moq` if it's not the `Moq` namespace?

Comment: Please also include the definition of `IInterface`

Comment: @PeterRitchie, Freesiah mentioned in one of his comments `private Mock<ICustomer> Moq { get; set; }`.

Comment: We'll need to see `ICustomer` too then...

Comment: @PeterRitchie,  he also said already in one of his comments *"Yeah! I missed to include it in ICustomer Interface"* (referring to method/unresolved symbol the compiler couldn't find...)  :-)